# Reading connection string defined in web.config from Windows service

Tags: c#, iis, web-config, windows-services, connection-string

I am trying to read connection string defined in web.config from a Windows service. The site name is `MySite` and is hosted on IIS at `http://localhost:31000` and physical path is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite`

Problem is following code always reads connection string from system level machine.config and not this site's web.config. I have tried different settings and code but same result. What am I doing wrong?

```
var configFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\web.config");
var vdm = new System.Web.Configuration.VirtualDirectoryMapping(configFile.DirectoryName, true, configFile.Name);
var wcfm = new System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationFileMap();
wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
ConnectionStringsSection csSection = config.ConnectionStrings;
for (int i = 0; i < ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count; i++)
{
  ConnectionStringSettings cs = csSection.ConnectionStrings[i];

  if (cs.Name == 'SQLServerConnectionString')
    return cs.ConnectionString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use System.Xmllibrary to read the config file and use select method to select the connection string node in the config file.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(@"The path");
        XmlNodeList xnodes = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/connectionStrings").ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode item in xnodes)
        {
            if (item.Attributes[0].Value == "ConnectionString")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes[1].Value);
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be much simpler. This is all you should need to read a connection string from the web.config file.

```
<ConnectionStrings>
 <add name="SQLServerConnectionString" connectionString="" />
</ConnectionStrings>
```

`var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: I don't want to define connection string in app.config. It is already defined in web.config from where I want to read (from inside Windows service)

Comment: What? each application should have its own configuration what if you deployed them on separate machines, then you have have to define it in multiple places, if you want a shared location may as well just read from some random file on the file system.